# Stripe different price subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-spark

I'm gonna setup subscription pricing model like this.

```
$19.99/mo for the first three months
$39.99/mo from the fourth month
```

I'm using laravel-cashier or laravel-spark 2.0.

How can I do this?

Comment: You set packages up in stripe

Comment: Can you please write in detail?

Comment: Look at stripes documentation on creating packages inside it. Cashier is literally just a way for you to use the stripe api. Leave most, if not all, of the package management up to stripe and leave as little up to laravel.

Comment: @Savlon could you please give me documentation link for this one? Thank you!